# edit default css of textfield produced by xeditable.js in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, x-editable

How can I edit the css for  angularjs's `xeditable.js` elements like textfield, textarea etc? They are produced by `xeditable.js` and I am able to overwrite the default css.

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow. Please share some code so we can help you.

Comment: May be this is more clear:
Pls have a look at this [xeditable textfield](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/25/).
In this example,markup, I want to reduce the size of text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly edit x-editable.css where you change the editable class

```
.editable-input.editable-has-buttons { width: 50px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/965/

Comment: I did not want to edit the x-editable.css. But it appears I can edit them in my css file as well. so thanks [babyAzerty](http://stackoverflow.com/users/836501/babyazerty)

Comment: You can override it. Just leave the x-editable.css and add my line in your own .css but remember to load your .css file after x-editable (so it overrides it)